# AVCapture pause screen after take photo

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, avcapture

I have used demo  example of avcapture ,i wanna display image in imagview in viewcontroller after take photo i have use code

```
{
 ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    NSInteger numberOfAssets = [group numberOfAssets];
    if (numberOfAssets > 0) {
        NSInteger lastIndex = numberOfAssets-1;
        [group enumerateAssetsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:lastIndex] options:0   usingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
            UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[result thumbnail]];
            if (thumbnail && thumbnail.size.width > 0) {
                imagviewlastimage.image = thumbnail;
                *stop = YES;
            }
        }];
    }
} failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
}];
```

to get last image from photo library but i am gatting second last image

and to redirect viewController after pick image i have wrote in

```
captureManagerStillImageCaptured:(AVCamCaptureManager *)captureManager delegate

ViewController *temp=[[ViewController alloc]init];

temp.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

[self presentModalViewController:temp animated:YES];
```

use as this , how to resolve this ? ya pause screen after take photo